# DeviceIoControl control codes

Tags: c#, deviceiocontrol

Im using deviceIoControl function in c# and I need a control code to define what will happen.
I'm looking for their values but I can only find their names,
for example FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS.

How can I know the value of the code for the decixeIoControl function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are looking for is defined in winioctl.h

```
#define FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM,24,METHOD_BUFFERED,FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
```

And the CTL_CODE is defined as follows:

```
#define CTL_CODE(DeviceType,Function,Method,Access) (((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method))
```

Therefore; with observing the values for the following constants: (all in winioctl.h)

```
DeviceType: #define FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM 0x00000009
Function: 24 (Passed in as constant)
Method: #define METHOD_BUFFERED 0
Access: #define FILE_ANY_ACCESS 0
```

The calculation results in:

```
(((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method))

= (9 << 16) | (0 << 14) | (24 << 2) | (0)

= 0x00090060 (hexadecimal)
```

or,

```
= 589920 (decimal)
```

You can calculate any other control codes this way, and also please check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol#remarks

Answer (score 0):

Because I couldn't find a good list of them already in hex form, and Google led me to this particular question, I'm posting them here:

```
0x002d4800 IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY
0x002d0800 IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_VERIFY2
0x002d4804 IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL
0x002d4808 IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA
0x002d480c IOCTL_STORAGE_LOAD_MEDIA
0x002d080c IOCTL_STORAGE_LOAD_MEDIA2
0x002d4810 IOCTL_STORAGE_RESERVE
0x002d4814 IOCTL_STORAGE_RELEASE
0x002d4818 IOCTL_STORAGE_FIND_NEW_DEVICES
0x002d0940 IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECTION_CONTROL
0x002d0944 IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL
0x002d0c00 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES
0x002d0c04 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES_EX
0x002d0c10 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER
0x002d0c14 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_HOTPLUG_INFO
0x002dcc18 IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_HOTPLUG_INFO
0x002d5000 IOCTL_STORAGE_RESET_BUS
0x002d5004 IOCTL_STORAGE_RESET_DEVICE
0x002d5014 IOCTL_STORAGE_BREAK_RESERVATION
0x002d5018 IOCTL_STORAGE_PERSISTENT_RESERVE_IN
0x002dd01c IOCTL_STORAGE_PERSISTENT_RESERVE_OUT
0x002d1080 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER
0x002d1084 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER_EX
0x002d1100 IOCTL_STORAGE_PREDICT_FAILURE
0x002d1104 IOCTL_STORAGE_FAILURE_PREDICTION_CONFIG
0x002d1108 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_COUNTERS
0x002d5140 IOCTL_STORAGE_READ_CAPACITY
0x002dd1c0 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_TELEMETRY
0x002dd1c4 IOCTL_STORAGE_DEVICE_TELEMETRY_NOTIFY
0x002dd1c8 IOCTL_STORAGE_DEVICE_TELEMETRY_QUERY_CAPS
0x002dd1cc IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_TELEMETRY_RAW
0x002dd200 IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD
0x002dd3c0 IOCTL_STORAGE_PROTOCOL_COMMAND
0x002d1400 IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY
0x002d9404 IOCTL_STORAGE_MANAGE_DATA_SET_ATTRIBUTES
0x002d5408 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_LB_PROVISIONING_MAP_RESOURCES
0x002d940c IOCTL_STORAGE_SET_PROPERTY
0x002d9640 IOCTL_STORAGE_REINITIALIZE_MEDIA
0x002d5800 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_BC_PROPERTIES
0x002dd804 IOCTL_STORAGE_ALLOCATE_BC_STREAM
0x002dd808 IOCTL_STORAGE_FREE_BC_STREAM
0x002d1880 IOCTL_STORAGE_CHECK_PRIORITY_HINT_SUPPORT
0x002dd884 IOCTL_STORAGE_START_DATA_INTEGRITY_CHECK
0x002dd888 IOCTL_STORAGE_STOP_DATA_INTEGRITY_CHECK
0x002dd000 OBSOLETE_IOCTL_STORAGE_RESET_BUS
0x002dd004 OBSOLETE_IOCTL_STORAGE_RESET_DEVICE
0x002d1c00 IOCTL_STORAGE_FIRMWARE_GET_INFO
0x002ddc04 IOCTL_STORAGE_FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD
0x002ddc08 IOCTL_STORAGE_FIRMWARE_ACTIVATE
0x002d1c80 IOCTL_STORAGE_ENABLE_IDLE_POWER
0x002d1c84 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_IDLE_POWERUP_REASON
0x002d1c88 IOCTL_STORAGE_POWER_ACTIVE
0x002d1c8c IOCTL_STORAGE_POWER_IDLE
0x002d1c90 IOCTL_STORAGE_EVENT_NOTIFICATION
0x002d1c94 IOCTL_STORAGE_DEVICE_POWER_CAP
0x002d1c98 IOCTL_STORAGE_RPMB_COMMAND
0x002ddc9c IOCTL_STORAGE_ATTRIBUTE_MANAGEMENT
0x002d1ca0 IOCTL_STORAGE_DIAGNOSTIC
0x002d1ca4 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_PHYSICAL_ELEMENT_STATUS
0x002d1cc0 IOCTL_STORAGE_REMOVE_ELEMENT_AND_TRUNCATE
0x002d1cc4 IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_INTERNAL_LOG
0x00590000 IOCTL_SCM_BUS_GET_LOGICAL_DEVICES
0x00590004 IOCTL_SCM_BUS_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICES
0x00590008 IOCTL_SCM_BUS_GET_REGIONS
0x00590c00 IOCTL_SCM_LD_GET_INTERLEAVE_SET
0x00591800 IOCTL_SCM_PD_QUERY_PROPERTY
0x00599804 IOCTL_SCM_PD_FIRMWARE_DOWNLOAD
0x00599808 IOCTL_SCM_PD_FIRMWARE_ACTIVATE
0x0059d80c IOCTL_SCM_PD_PASSTHROUGH
0x00591810 IOCTL_SCM_PD_UPDATE_MANAGEMENT_STATUS
0x00599814 IOCTL_SCM_PD_REINITIALIZE_MEDIA
0x00070000 IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY
0x00074004 IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO
0x0007c008 IOCTL_DISK_SET_PARTITION_INFO
0x0007400c IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT
0x0007c010 IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT
0x00070014 IOCTL_DISK_VERIFY
0x0007c018 IOCTL_DISK_FORMAT_TRACKS
0x0007c01c IOCTL_DISK_REASSIGN_BLOCKS
0x00070020 IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE
0x00070024 IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITABLE
0x00070028 IOCTL_DISK_LOGGING
0x0007c02c IOCTL_DISK_FORMAT_TRACKS_EX
0x00070030 IOCTL_DISK_HISTOGRAM_STRUCTURE
0x00070034 IOCTL_DISK_HISTOGRAM_DATA
0x00070038 IOCTL_DISK_HISTOGRAM_RESET
0x0007003c IOCTL_DISK_REQUEST_STRUCTURE
0x00070040 IOCTL_DISK_REQUEST_DATA
0x00070060 IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE_OFF
0x00070044 IOCTL_DISK_CONTROLLER_NUMBER
0x00074080 SMART_GET_VERSION
0x0007c084 SMART_SEND_DRIVE_COMMAND
0x0007c088 SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA
0x00070048 IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX
0x0007c04c IOCTL_DISK_SET_PARTITION_INFO_EX
0x00070050 IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX
0x0007c054 IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX
0x0007c058 IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK
0x0007405c IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO
0x000700a0 IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX
0x0007c0a4 IOCTL_DISK_REASSIGN_BLOCKS_EX
0x0007c0c8 IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_DRIVE_SIZE
0x0007c0d0 IOCTL_DISK_GROW_PARTITION
0x000740d4 IOCTL_DISK_GET_CACHE_INFORMATION
0x0007c0d8 IOCTL_DISK_SET_CACHE_INFORMATION
0x000740dc OBSOLETE_DISK_GET_WRITE_CACHE_STATE
0x0007c100 IOCTL_DISK_DELETE_DRIVE_LAYOUT
0x00070140 IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES
0x0007c3cc IOCTL_DISK_FORMAT_DRIVE
0x000703e0 IOCTL_DISK_SENSE_DEVICE
0x00074800 IOCTL_DISK_CHECK_VERIFY
0x00074804 IOCTL_DISK_MEDIA_REMOVAL
0x00074808 IOCTL_DISK_EJECT_MEDIA
0x0007480c IOCTL_DISK_LOAD_MEDIA
0x00074810 IOCTL_DISK_RESERVE
0x00074814 IOCTL_DISK_RELEASE
0x00074818 IOCTL_DISK_FIND_NEW_DEVICES
0x00070c00 IOCTL_DISK_GET_MEDIA_TYPES
0x000700f0 IOCTL_DISK_GET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES
0x0007c0f4 IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES
0x0007c210 IOCTL_DISK_RESET_SNAPSHOT_INFO
0x00304000 IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PARAMETERS
0x00304004 IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_STATUS
0x00304008 IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA
0x0030c010 IOCTL_CHANGER_SET_ACCESS
0x0030c014 IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_ELEMENT_STATUS
0x00304018 IOCTL_CHANGER_INITIALIZE_ELEMENT_STATUS
0x0030401c IOCTL_CHANGER_SET_POSITION
0x00304020 IOCTL_CHANGER_EXCHANGE_MEDIUM
0x00304024 IOCTL_CHANGER_MOVE_MEDIUM
0x00304028 IOCTL_CHANGER_REINITIALIZE_TRANSPORT
0x0030c02c IOCTL_CHANGER_QUERY_VOLUME_TAGS
0x001b007c IOCTL_SERIAL_LSRMST_INSERT
0x00370200 IOCTL_SERENUM_EXPOSE_HARDWARE
0x00370204 IOCTL_SERENUM_REMOVE_HARDWARE
0x00370208 IOCTL_SERENUM_PORT_DESC
0x0037020c IOCTL_SERENUM_GET_PORT_NAME
0x00090000 FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK_LEVEL_1
0x00090004 FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK_LEVEL_2
0x00090008 FSCTL_REQUEST_BATCH_OPLOCK
0x0009000c FSCTL_OPLOCK_BREAK_ACKNOWLEDGE
0x00090010 FSCTL_OPBATCH_ACK_CLOSE_PENDING
0x00090014 FSCTL_OPLOCK_BREAK_NOTIFY
0x00090018 FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME
0x0009001c FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME
0x00090020 FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME
0x00090028 FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_MOUNTED
0x0009002c FSCTL_IS_PATHNAME_VALID
0x00090030 FSCTL_MARK_VOLUME_DIRTY
0x0009003b FSCTL_QUERY_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS
0x0009003c FSCTL_GET_COMPRESSION
0x0009c040 FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION
0x0009004f FSCTL_SET_BOOTLOADER_ACCESSED
0x00090050 FSCTL_OPLOCK_BREAK_ACK_NO_2
0x00090054 FSCTL_INVALIDATE_VOLUMES
0x00090058 FSCTL_QUERY_FAT_BPB
0x0009005c FSCTL_REQUEST_FILTER_OPLOCK
0x00090060 FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS
0x00090064 FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA
0x00090068 FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD
0x0009006f FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP
0x00090073 FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS
0x00090074 FSCTL_MOVE_FILE
0x00090078 FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_DIRTY
0x00090083 FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO
0x0009008f FSCTL_FIND_FILES_BY_SID
0x00090098 FSCTL_SET_OBJECT_ID
0x0009009c FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID
0x000900a0 FSCTL_DELETE_OBJECT_ID
0x000900a4 FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT
0x000900a8 FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT
0x000900ac FSCTL_DELETE_REPARSE_POINT
0x000900b3 FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA
0x000940b7 FSCTL_SECURITY_ID_CHECK
0x000900bb FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL
0x000900bc FSCTL_SET_OBJECT_ID_EXTENDED
0x000900c0 FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID
0x000900c4 FSCTL_SET_SPARSE
0x000980c8 FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA
0x000940cf FSCTL_QUERY_ALLOCATED_RANGES
0x000980d0 FSCTL_ENABLE_UPGRADE
0x000900d7 FSCTL_SET_ENCRYPTION
0x000900db FSCTL_ENCRYPTION_FSCTL_IO
0x000900df FSCTL_WRITE_RAW_ENCRYPTED
0x000900e3 FSCTL_READ_RAW_ENCRYPTED
0x000900e7 FSCTL_CREATE_USN_JOURNAL
0x000900eb FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA
0x000900ef FSCTL_WRITE_USN_CLOSE_RECORD
0x000900f0 FSCTL_EXTEND_VOLUME
0x000900f4 FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL
0x000900f8 FSCTL_DELETE_USN_JOURNAL
0x000900fc FSCTL_MARK_HANDLE
0x00090100 FSCTL_SIS_COPYFILE
0x0009c104 FSCTL_SIS_LINK_FILES
0x00090117 FSCTL_RECALL_FILE
0x0009411e FSCTL_READ_FROM_PLEX
0x00090120 FSCTL_FILE_PREFETCH
0x00098130 FSCTL_MAKE_MEDIA_COMPATIBLE
0x00098134 FSCTL_SET_DEFECT_MANAGEMENT
0x00090138 FSCTL_QUERY_SPARING_INFO
0x0009013c FSCTL_QUERY_ON_DISK_VOLUME_INFO
0x00090140 FSCTL_SET_VOLUME_COMPRESSION_STATE
0x00098144 FSCTL_TXFS_MODIFY_RM
0x00094148 FSCTL_TXFS_QUERY_RM_INFORMATION
0x00098150 FSCTL_TXFS_ROLLFORWARD_REDO
0x00098154 FSCTL_TXFS_ROLLFORWARD_UNDO
0x00098158 FSCTL_TXFS_START_RM
0x0009815c FSCTL_TXFS_SHUTDOWN_RM
0x00094160 FSCTL_TXFS_READ_BACKUP_INFORMATION
0x00098164 FSCTL_TXFS_WRITE_BACKUP_INFORMATION
0x00098168 FSCTL_TXFS_CREATE_SECONDARY_RM
0x0009416c FSCTL_TXFS_GET_METADATA_INFO
0x00094170 FSCTL_TXFS_GET_TRANSACTED_VERSION
0x00098178 FSCTL_TXFS_SAVEPOINT_INFORMATION
0x0009817c FSCTL_TXFS_CREATE_MINIVERSION
0x0009418c FSCTL_TXFS_TRANSACTION_ACTIVE
0x00090194 FSCTL_SET_ZERO_ON_DEALLOCATION
0x00090198 FSCTL_SET_REPAIR
0x0009019c FSCTL_GET_REPAIR
0x000901a0 FSCTL_WAIT_FOR_REPAIR
0x000901a8 FSCTL_INITIATE_REPAIR
0x000901af FSCTL_CSC_INTERNAL
0x000901b0 FSCTL_SHRINK_VOLUME
0x000901b4 FSCTL_SET_SHORT_NAME_BEHAVIOR
0x000901b8 FSCTL_DFSR_SET_GHOST_HANDLE_STATE
0x000941e4 FSCTL_TXFS_LIST_TRANSACTIONS
0x000901e8 FSCTL_QUERY_PAGEFILE_ENCRYPTION
0x000901ec FSCTL_RESET_VOLUME_ALLOCATION_HINTS
0x000901f0 FSCTL_QUERY_DEPENDENT_VOLUME
0x000901f4 FSCTL_SD_GLOBAL_CHANGE
0x000901f8 FSCTL_TXFS_READ_BACKUP_INFORMATION2
0x000901fc FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER
0x00090200 FSCTL_TXFS_WRITE_BACKUP_INFORMATION2
0x00090204 FSCTL_FILE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION
0x00098208 FSCTL_FILE_LEVEL_TRIM
0x00090230 FSCTL_GET_BOOT_AREA_INFO
0x00090234 FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_BASE
0x00090238 FSCTL_SET_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE
0x0009023c FSCTL_QUERY_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE
0x00090240 FSCTL_REQUEST_OPLOCK
0x00090244 FSCTL_CSV_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x00090248 FSCTL_IS_CSV_FILE
0x0009024c FSCTL_QUERY_FILE_SYSTEM_RECOGNITION
0x00090250 FSCTL_CSV_GET_VOLUME_PATH_NAME
0x00090254 FSCTL_CSV_GET_VOLUME_NAME_FOR_VOLUME_MOUNT_POINT
0x00090258 FSCTL_CSV_GET_VOLUME_PATH_NAMES_FOR_VOLUME_NAME
0x0009025c FSCTL_IS_FILE_ON_CSV_VOLUME
0x00090260 FSCTL_CORRUPTION_HANDLING
0x00094264 FSCTL_OFFLOAD_READ
0x00098268 FSCTL_OFFLOAD_WRITE
0x0009026c FSCTL_CSV_INTERNAL
0x00090270 FSCTL_SET_PURGE_FAILURE_MODE
0x00090277 FSCTL_QUERY_FILE_LAYOUT
0x00090278 FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_OWNED_BYCSVFS
0x0009027c FSCTL_GET_INTEGRITY_INFORMATION
0x0009c280 FSCTL_SET_INTEGRITY_INFORMATION
0x00090284 FSCTL_QUERY_FILE_REGIONS
0x000902af FSCTL_RKF_INTERNAL
0x000902b0 FSCTL_SCRUB_DATA
0x0009c2b4 FSCTL_REPAIR_COPIES
0x000902b8 FSCTL_DISABLE_LOCAL_BUFFERING
0x000902bc FSCTL_CSV_MGMT_LOCK
0x000902c0 FSCTL_CSV_QUERY_DOWN_LEVEL_FILE_SYSTEM_CHARACTERISTICS
0x000902c4 FSCTL_ADVANCE_FILE_ID
0x000902c8 FSCTL_CSV_SYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x000902cc FSCTL_CSV_QUERY_VETO_FILE_DIRECT_IO
0x000902d0 FSCTL_WRITE_USN_REASON
0x000902d4 FSCTL_CSV_CONTROL
0x000902d8 FSCTL_GET_REFS_VOLUME_DATA
0x000902e4 FSCTL_CSV_H_BREAKING_SYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x000902ec FSCTL_QUERY_STORAGE_CLASSES
0x000902f0 FSCTL_QUERY_REGION_INFO
0x000902f4 FSCTL_USN_TRACK_MODIFIED_RANGES
0x00090300 FSCTL_QUERY_SHARED_VIRTUAL_DISK_SUPPORT
0x00090304 FSCTL_SVHDX_SYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x00090308 FSCTL_SVHDX_SET_INITIATOR_INFORMATION
0x0009030c FSCTL_SET_EXTERNAL_BACKING
0x00090310 FSCTL_GET_EXTERNAL_BACKING
0x00090314 FSCTL_DELETE_EXTERNAL_BACKING
0x00090318 FSCTL_ENUM_EXTERNAL_BACKING
0x0009031f FSCTL_ENUM_OVERLAY
0x00098330 FSCTL_ADD_OVERLAY
0x00098334 FSCTL_REMOVE_OVERLAY
0x00098338 FSCTL_UPDATE_OVERLAY
0x0009c340 FSCTL_SHUFFLE_FILE
0x00098344 FSCTL_DUPLICATE_EXTENTS_TO_FILE
0x0009034c FSCTL_SPARSE_OVERALLOCATE
0x00090350 FSCTL_STORAGE_QOS_CONTROL
0x0009035c FSCTL_INITIATE_FILE_METADATA_OPTIMIZATION
0x00090360 FSCTL_QUERY_FILE_METADATA_OPTIMIZATION
0x00090364 FSCTL_SVHDX_ASYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x00090368 FSCTL_GET_WOF_VERSION
0x0009036c FSCTL_HCS_SYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x00090370 FSCTL_HCS_ASYNC_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x00090377 FSCTL_QUERY_EXTENT_READ_CACHE_INFO
0x0009037b FSCTL_QUERY_REFS_VOLUME_COUNTER_INFO
0x0009037c FSCTL_CLEAN_VOLUME_METADATA
0x00090380 FSCTL_SET_INTEGRITY_INFORMATION_EX
0x00090384 FSCTL_SUSPEND_OVERLAY
0x00090388 FSCTL_VIRTUAL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY
0x0009038c FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS_EX
0x00090390 FSCTL_QUERY_VOLUME_CONTAINER_STATE
0x00090394 FSCTL_SET_LAYER_ROOT
0x0009039b FSCTL_QUERY_DIRECT_ACCESS_EXTENTS
0x0009039c FSCTL_NOTIFY_STORAGE_SPACE_ALLOCATION
0x000903a0 FSCTL_SSDI_STORAGE_REQUEST
0x000903a4 FSCTL_QUERY_DIRECT_IMAGE_ORIGINAL_BASE
0x000903ab FSCTL_READ_UNPRIVILEGED_USN_JOURNAL
0x000983ac FSCTL_GHOST_FILE_EXTENTS
0x000903b0 FSCTL_QUERY_GHOSTED_FILE_EXTENTS
0x000903b4 FSCTL_UNMAP_SPACE
0x000903b8 FSCTL_HCS_SYNC_NO_WRITE_TUNNEL_REQUEST
0x000903c4 FSCTL_STREAMS_QUERY_PARAMETERS
0x000903c8 FSCTL_STREAMS_ASSOCIATE_ID
0x000903cc FSCTL_STREAMS_QUERY_ID
0x000903d3 FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS_AND_REFCOUNT
0x000903d4 FSCTL_QUERY_VOLUME_NUMA_INFO
0x000903d8 FSCTL_REFS_DEALLOCATE_RANGES
0x000903dc FSCTL_QUERY_REFS_SMR_VOLUME_INFO
0x000903e0 FSCTL_SET_REFS_SMR_VOLUME_GC_PARAMETERS
0x000903e4 FSCTL_SET_REFS_FILE_STRICTLY_SEQUENTIAL
0x000983e8 FSCTL_DUPLICATE_EXTENTS_TO_FILE_EX
0x000903ec FSCTL_QUERY_BAD_RANGES
0x000903f0 FSCTL_SET_DAX_ALLOC_ALIGNMENT_HINT
0x000903f4 FSCTL_DELETE_CORRUPTED_REFS_CONTAINER
0x000903f8 FSCTL_SCRUB_UNDISCOVERABLE_ID
0x000903fc FSCTL_NOTIFY_DATA_CHANGE
0x00090400 FSCTL_START_VIRTUALIZATION_INSTANCE_EX
0x00090404 FSCTL_ENCRYPTION_KEY_CONTROL
0x00090408 FSCTL_VIRTUAL_STORAGE_SET_BEHAVIOR
0x0009040c FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT_EX
0x0009c420 FSCTL_REARRANGE_FILE
0x00090424 FSCTL_VIRTUAL_STORAGE_PASSTHROUGH
0x0009042b FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_COUNT
0x0009042c FSCTL_ENABLE_PER_IO_FLAGS
0x00560000 IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
0x0056c008 IOCTL_VOLUME_ONLINE
0x0056c00c IOCTL_VOLUME_OFFLINE
0x00560030 IOCTL_VOLUME_IS_CLUSTERED
0x00560038 IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_GPT_ATTRIBUTES
```